# Can I specify a custom location for `updatedb.conf`?

Tags: locate, updatedb

Can I specify a custom location for `updatedb.conf`?

I am using mlocate/updatedb with a private data base.
I do not have root credentials on this system and I cannot and do not want to change the `/etc/updatedb.conf/`. I just want to make my own custom `updatedb.conf`, and specify directories which I want to exclude there (I know that I can specify them with `-e` on the command line, this is what I have been doing so far, but it is getting a very long list so I want to move it to a separate file). Is this possible? I could specify it in `updatedb.conf`... but of course not if it's it `/etc/` so I want my own, custom one. The man pages for updatedb, mlocate, updatedb.conf do not tell me how or if this is possible.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Ubuntu release 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `/etc/updatedb.conf` cannot be omitted.

But you can use environmental variables and command aliases to trim you command line length:

If you have too many paths to prune, just put it all in env variable:
`export MYPRUNEPATHS="/var/cache /var/www /var/lib/docker"`

then update your custom db:
`updatedb -o ~/.mymlocate.db --prunepaths $MYPRUNEPATHS`

To make `$MYPRUNEPATHS` persistent, add the first command I've write above to your ~/.bashrc (or ~/.zshrc).

You can also use command aliases in the ~/.bashrc:

```
# My mlocate
export MYPRUNEPATHS="/var/cache /var/www /var/lib/docker"
alias myupdateb="updatedb -o ~/.mymlocate.db --prunepaths '$MYPRUNEPATHS'"
alias mylocate="locate -d ~/.mymlocate.db"
```

Now you can run in bash just `myupdateb` to update you custom mlocate db, and `mylocate something` to search within this db.

p.s. Don't forget to execute `source ~/.bashrc` to apply your changes made in `~/.bashrc`